# Creating a Ship Generator Method in Python (newer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to create the game Battleship with python3 with the user playing the CPU. I've had some issues with the ship generator which is where the script places its own ships. The method takes in the arguments 'map' which is the 2d array of the map (the array must be filled with the letter "O" which resembles an empty map)and 'numtimes' which is the count for how many ships should be placed (The first ship starts out with a size of 2 blocks, and increases by one every time a new ship is created). Ships are marked with letters depending on the alphabet. For example, if 2 ships were made, ship number one would be made up of the letter 'A' and ship number two would be marked with the letter 'B'.
Now for the question:
Whenever I run the method for a 10x10 map for 4 ships, the map only returns with one ship on the map with a block length of 1. Here's the outcome when I run my unfinished script:

```
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O A O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O
```

Here's the method:

```
from random import randint
from string import ascii_uppercase

def shipmaker(map, numtimes):  #only works if map is a square filled with 'O' & max numtimes is 4
    asci = ascii_uppercase #alphabet

    themap = len(map)-1 #array/board size
    truth = False #Used for first while loop below
    for i in range(numtimes):
        while truth == False:
            size = 2+i #size increases along with numtimes. Ship number one is two units long
            direction = randint(0,1) #This depicts whether the ship will be vertical or horizontal
            while True: #For the first coordinate
                row = randint(0,themap-size)  #row of first coordinate
                col = randint(0,themap-size)  #column of first coordinate
                if map[row][col] == "O":      #If the coordinate was "O", it hasn't been used yet. The ships cannot overlap each other
                    map[row][col]=asci[size-2]
                    break
            for x in range(size-1):
                if direction == 1: #vertical
                    if map[row+x][col]!="O":  #further continues breaking the loop if coordinate was already used
                        break
                    else:     #if coordinate wasn't used
                        row+=x
                        map[row][col] = asci[size-2]   #Makes ship equal to letter corresponding to the alphabet
                else: #horizontal; Same thing below except the column coordinates are changed since this is horizontal
                    if map[row][col+x]!="O":
                        break
                    else:
                        col+=x
                        map[row][col] = asci[size - 2]
            if map[row][col] == asci[size-2]:
                truth = True    #breaks the while loop if everything was good and goes on to the next ship in the superior for loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem resides on these 3 lines:

```
truth = False
for i in range(numtimes):
    while truth == False:
```

When you break out of your while loop, and start on the next ship, you never reset truth to be `True`, so the while loop is skipped for all remaining ships. Instead, place `truth` inside the for loop, like so:

```
for i in range(numtimes):
    truth = False
    while truth == False:
```

Comment: Wow, I am ignorant. Thank you

Comment: If that was indeed your issue, feel free to accept this answer as correct.